# Como fazer com que o reload page demore 10 segundos

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache-cordova

Eu tenho este código aqui, porem ele esta sempre a fazer o reload a pagina.

```
script type="text/javascript">
function autoRefreshPage()
{
    window.location = window.location.href;
    setInterval('autoRefreshPage()', 10000);
}
```

Eu queria que quando fizesse o click ele demorasse 10 segundos para dar refresh da pagina.

Comment: Da uma olhada: https://github.com/kidh0/jquery.idle

Comment: Click aonde????

Comment: @JuniorNunes Para quê complicar se o código pode ser facilmente adaptado para ficar correto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao fazer

```
window.location = window.location.href;
```

A pagina vai recarregar logo, deixando de executar o setInterval;
Para corrigir basta alterar a função por:

```
function autoRefreshPage()
{
    setInterval(function () {location.reload();}, 10000);
}
```

Comment: Resposta correcta, obrigado!